# SQL syntax error [PHP|MYSQL]

Tags: php, mysql, session, syntax

I work'd today on a public profile for my website but I hava problem .

I enter all information but when I press submit I get :

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id=1' at line 3

Code :

```
 // contact to database

/// connection is OK 

//Get data in local variable
$v_name=$_POST['name'];
$v_age=$_POST['age'];
$v_job=$_POST['job'];
$v_interes=$_POST['interes'];
$v_hobbies=$_POST['hobbies'];
$v_family=$_POST['family'];
$v_pub_mail=$_POST['pub_mail'];
$v_profimg=$_POST['profimg'];
$v_about=$_POST['about'];

// check for null values
if ($v_name==""  /*or $v_msg==""*/)
echo "All fields must be entered, hit back button and re-enter information";
else{
$query="insert into user(name,pub_mail,age,job,interes,hobbies,family,about) values ('$v_name','$v_age','$v_job','$v_interes','$v_hobbies','$v_family','$v_pub_mail','$v_profimg','$v_about') WHERE id='$usrid'";
mysql_query($query)  or die(mysql_error());
echo "Your profile was updated .";
}
```

Comment: Talk about injection risk.  Try scrubbing your inputs before inserting them.. or better yet, use PDO prepared statements.

Comment: On a side note, you're inserting nine values into eight columns. You might wanna check that.

Comment: And one of the fields is out of order.

Comment: I will recheck and try to fix it ! Thanks for help .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`INSERT` doesn't have a `WHERE` clause. If you need to update an existing record then you should be using `UPDATE` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you should not use `WHERE` clause with an `INSERT`.

```
$query="insert into user(name,pub_mail,age,job,interes,hobbies,family,about) values ('$v_name','$v_age','$v_job','$v_interes','$v_hobbies','$v_family','$v_pub_mail','$v_profimg','$v_about');
```

I think you want to make an UPDATE instead of an INSERT ...

(you insertion/update is not secure by the way, don't forget to use `addslashes`)

Comment: If I don't use where , then how can he insert the data to the profile I want ?

Comment: @GerculyRobert There's no such thing as inserting the data "to the profile you want". What you're thinking of is achieved by `INSERT`ing `$usrid` into `id` as part of your `INSERT` statement.

Comment: @GerculyRobert Wait a minute. Your form looks like it's used to add entries to a database, not to change existing entries. Make sure that `UPDATE`ing an already existent entry is indeed what you want, and not just entering in a new entry with an existent id.

Comment: Thank you for your attention but I'm ganna wait with this script for a while . I Will start learn php and PDO . My traffic exchange script is old and I think I will need to update it .